# Set value of register to 64-bit integer in RISC-V

Tags: assembly, cpu-architecture, riscv, instruction-set

The task is to set the value of a0 to 0xbadcab1e. a0 is a 64-bit integer. I may only use sll, slli, srl, srli, sra, srai, add, addi, sub, lui. "Hint: The addi instruction sets the 12 bottom bits of the target register. But problem: it sign-extends it! Can you work around it?"

I wrote the following code and I do not understand why it doesn't work:

```
lui a0, 0xB 
srli a0, a0, 36 
addi t1, zero, 0x1E 
lui t2, 0xBADCA 
srl t2, t2, 32 
add a0, a0, t1 
add a0, a0, t2
```

Comment: `lui` / `srl 32` will shift out all the bits; single-step it in a debugger and watch register values.  GCC and Clang both use only 3 instructions, since that constant is a 32-bit constant left-shifted by 1: https://godbolt.org/z/b3Yq6M8ab

Comment: sign-extend is setting all upper bits to 1 when the top bit of what is extended is 1. A number whose bits are all 1 is `-1` in two's complement, so you can add `1` to the upper part to cancel this `addi`'s `-1`.

Comment: First you will need to know, in 64 bits is 0xbadcab1e equal to 0x00000000badcab1e or 0xffffffffbadcab1e, or 0xbadcab1e00000000 (which is not the same number so maybe this needs rethink).  Next, try a compiler to see what it does: `long long foo1() { return  0xbadcab1eull; }`.  Note that in 64-bit mode, `lui` sign extends its 20 bit immediate into the upper 32-bits of the register.

Comment: BTW, `0xbadcab1e` as a C integer constant has type `unsigned` (because it's written in hex and fits in 32-bit unsigned but not 32-bit signed).  In my earlier comment, I didn't count the digits and had been assuming it was already 64-bit, but it's not.  https://godbolt.org/z/bo96KMKPj shows `return (int)0xbadcab1e` (sign-extend) vs. `return 0xbadcab1eULL` (zero-extend by using a left-shift so the upper bit of the LUI immediate can be zero).  Also, `lui t2, 0xBADCA` / `srl t2, t2, 32` doesn't produce `0`, it produces `0x00000000FFFFFFFF`.